# Open new pages also in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

I have created an app with a twebBrowser in it. Problem is when i click on some link, in say gmail, it opens in a new window of my default browser( which is IE). how do i make it work like firefox or chrome etc. which opens the clicked links in their windows. The url's should open in the TWebBrowser's window. Must i create a new Form at runtime with TWebBrowser in it at runtime for that? Code not needed as such, ideas will do

Thanks in Advance.

P.S.  My org blocks Gmail, Facebook etc. , However through my TWebBrowser, i can open them. Can my QA ppl see that in their log? My guess will be no, since then they would block it. What is your comment on this

Comment: About your "PS": Your sites are most likely blocked at network level, not at application level; If your default IE browser can't access them, your `TWebBrowser` will not be able to access them either. Not to mention `TWebBrowser` is actually a `IE` window, so it really *is* the same browser.

Comment: But my IE cannot access the sites, my TWebBrowser can.. Thats what i said.

Comment: Yes, they can see it in their logs. But if they are blocking sites using IE options instead of network/router settings (otherwise I can't explain that your TWebBrowser can access them because as @Cosmin said that is actually an IE Window), you might (!) get away with it. However, ask yourself why your organisation blocks these sites (people spending too much time on them?) and whether it is wise to try and thwart company policy like this.

Comment: @marjan: Sometimes it is necessary for ppl to access 'outside' sites as they have a life outside of the company too. I dont plan on wasting my time on these sites, sometimes maybe yeah, i will use it :)

Comment: @sunandan: I wasn't saying *you* were spending too much time on these sites, but that other people doing so may be the reason they are blocked and that you need to ask yourself whether it is wise to try and circumvent company policy on this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TWebBrowser` has an `OnNewWindow2` event. Assuming the form holding the `TWebBrowser` is named `Form1` and the web-control itself is named `WebBrowser1`, write a handler like this:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NewWindow2(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool);
var NF: TForm1;
begin
  NF := TForm1.Create(Application);
  NF.Visible := True;
  NF.WebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser;
  ppDisp := NF.WebBrowser1.DefaultInterface;
end;
```

This will create a new window, with a new `TWebBrowser` when the "click" is supposed to lead to a new window.